# Failsafe integration tests running on jetty-maven-plugin hanging or/and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven, jetty, integration-testing, permgen, documentum

When running maven failsafe plugin with jetty maven plugin with the following configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.15.v20140411</version>
    <configuration>
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
        </webAppConfig>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8181</port>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
        <contextXml>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-war</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <versionenter code here>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
        </includes>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${documentum.home}</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m</argLine>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Maven hangs on the following lines:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.fee.services.dctmsp.test.FooSpRepositoryServiceTest
Getting session manager...  OK - took 4932 ms
Getting session...          OK - took 1085 ms
serviceFactory: com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory@2743724e
spRepositoryService: JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-: Stub for http://localhost:8181/fooSP/services/fooSP/FooSpRepositoryService
```

Sometimes i get this:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet
SEVERE: caught throwable
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.DfsException.<init>(DfsException.java:91)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.DfsException.<init>(DfsException.java:73)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.ServiceException.<init>(ServiceException.java:56)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.ServiceInvocationException.<init>(ServiceInvocationException.java:36)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:35)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.handler.AuthorizationHandler.authenticate(AuthorizationHandler.java:130)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.handler.AuthorizationHandler.handleMessage(AuthorizationHandler.java:55)
        at com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.impl.handler.AuthorizationHandler.handleMessage(AuthorizationHandler.java:1)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessage(HandlerProcessor.java:284)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersRequest(HandlerProcessor.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ServerSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnRequest(ServerSOAPHandlerTube.java:134)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processRequest(HandlerTube.java:116)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:243)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:471)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
```

And some other times I get this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.foo.services.dctmsp.test.FooSpRepositoryServiceTest
Getting session manager...  OK - took 5914 ms
Getting session...          OK - took 1072 ms
serviceFactory: com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.ServiceFactory@111edceb
spRepositoryService: JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-: Stub for http://localhost:8181/fooSP/services/fooSP/FooSpRepositoryService
2014-09-18 14:32:50.353:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /fooSP/services/fooSP/FooSpRepositoryService
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2014-09-18 14:32:51.871:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:Error for /fooSP/services/fooSP/FooSpRepositoryService
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Now, I have tried with different settings for MaxPermSize, but it doesn't seem to help, everything ranging from 64M to 5000M.

Here is the test code that I am running:

```
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public class FooSpRepositoryServiceTest extends FooSpCommon {

    IFooSpRepositoryService spRepositoryService = null;
    ArrayList<ISbDokument> dokumenter = new ArrayList<ISbDokument>();
    ServiceFactory serviceFactory = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        try {
            serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.getInstance();
            spRepositoryService = serviceFactory.getRemoteService(IFooSpRepositoryService.class, serviceContext,
                  FOO_SERVICE_MODULE, FOO_SP_HOST);
            System.out.println("serviceFactory: " +  serviceFactory);
            System.out.println("spRepositoryService: " + spRepositoryService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        try {

            if (dokumenter.size() > 0) {
                for (ISbDokument dokument : dokumenter) {
                    if (dokument.isCheckedOut())
                        dokument.checkin(true, "CURRENT");
                    dokument.destroyAllVersions();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (session != null) {
            sessionMgr.release(session);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test_dummy() {
        String dummystring = "hello";
        assertEquals(dummystring, "hello");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_dummy1() {
        assertTrue(serviceFactory != null);
        assertTrue(spRepositoryService != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_getFormatName_Text() throws ServiceException {
        String formatName = spRepositoryService.getFormatName(REPOSITORY, "txt");
        assertTrue(formatName != null);
        assertTrue(!formatName.equalsIgnoreCase(""));
        assertEquals(formatName, "crtext");
    }
}
```

The problem apparently occurs in the method test_getFormatName_Text when spRepositoryService.getFormatName is invoked, because the other tests don't fail. What happens whenever I don't get any "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" is that it hangs forever.

Comment: seems like you are placing jvm parameters on a wrong place

Comment: Thanks for replying Miki. Do you have any suggestions about where the jvm parameters should be placed?

Comment: Nope, I only know Documentum well from tagged content. If you could offer a broader picture, maybe I could give some hint if its related with Documentum.

Comment: Miki, I have added the test code. Thanks for replying